# Dart - How do I make detect If variable value is exist in a list

Tags: dart

How do I make detect if variable data is a list or not? It always giving me an error `The argument type 'List<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Pattern'.` Can someone help me out?

```
var lister = ["Hello", "There!"];
var data = "There";

void main() {
  if (data.contains(lister)) {
    print("Yeah, it's in a list");
  } else {
    print("Nope, it's not in a list");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

```dart
var lister = ["Hello", "There!"];
var data = "There";

void main() {
  int? itemIndex = lister.indexWhere((item) => item.contains(data));

  if (itemIndex > 0) {
    print("Yeah, it's in a list");
  } else {
    print("Nope, it's not in a list");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error since `.contains` is being called on the `data` (which is a String), whereas you want to call it on `lister`. So you should do:

```
var lister = ["Hello", "There!"];
var data = "There";

void main() {
  if (lister.contains(data)) {
    print("Yeah, it's in a list");
  } else {
    print("Nope, it's not in a list");
  }
}
```